# Type 'myInterface' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined' Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an error that I don't understand, I have a json and I made an interface when I try to loop on it I get an error in my html.

the json format is quite complex for me.

thanks.

[the error in pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W83Ra.png)

**json**

```
{
  "images": [
    {
      "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m82woaL5AD1rro1o5o1_1280.jpg",
      "id": "MTgwODA3MA"
    },
}
```

**interface**

```
export interface Catlist {
    images: Image[];
}

export interface Image {
    url: string;
    id:  string;
}
```

**service**

```
  getAllCat(): Observable<Catlist> {
    return this.http.get<Catlist>("/api/data/cats.json");
  }
```

**ts.file**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.unsubscribe = this.catService.getAllCat().subscribe((res: Catlist) => {
      this.data = res;
    })
  }
```

**html**

```
<div class="separate" *ngFor="let cat of data">
    <img [src]="cat.url">
</div>
```

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid. You can validate JSON with [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com). Please post code, logs and error messages as text, not as images. `data` is of type `CatList` and not iterable. You probably mean `data.images`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, you're trying to loop over an object of type `Catlist`. You probably meant to iterate over the `Catlist.images` array.

```
<div class="separate" *ngFor="let cat of data.images">
    <img [src]="cat.url">
</div>
```